# Get list of all Realms in OpenAM

Tags: openam

How Can I get a list of all Realms with name and description using OpenAM API call?

Comment: http://java.net/projects/opensso/lists/users/archive/2010-07/message/187

Answer (score -1):

If you are using the ClientSDK then you can see a sample implementation here for example:
http://sources.forgerock.org/browse/openam/trunk/openam/openam-cli/openam-cli-impl/src/main/java/com/sun/identity/cli/realm/SearchRealms.java?hb=true